# Azure VM and SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

My web project uses an software, which need to be installed on destination PC. So, I have to use Azure VM and no way to use Azure Cloud Service, right?
Also, can I use SQL Azure with Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can install any third party software on Azure Web/Worker roles (Cloud Services), as long as the installer supports a quiet/unattemded install from a command line with switches. Learn more how to do this via [StartUp tasks here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx).

As for Azure SQL Database - you can use with any combination of services. Even with on-premises only solution. You have to take care of [Firewall rules.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee621782.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Database tends to be much less expensive than a VM with SQL Server installed. It won't run on a VM but you can access an Azure SQL database from an VM or web application in the same way you access local databases - You just set the connection string to the Azure SQL connection string.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent post that can help you with in order to understand how to configure customization with cloud services.

[microsoft-azure-cloud-services-part-4-lifecycle-and-customization-of-your-vm](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/microsoft-azure-cloud-services-part-4-lifecycle-and-customization-of-your-vm/)

As the link explains there is nothing persisted on a cloud service VM but this is not a limitation instead a good practice which allows easy scaling out by adding more instances if required.

You can use Azure PaaS SQL just like a SQL server installed on a different server then your web server with some limitations. Please have a look at the link below from MSDN to understand these limitations.

[sql-database-transact-sql-information](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-transact-sql-information/)